# DropdownButton can't update it's value(null)

Tags: dart, flutter

The full page code is very long but my DropdownButton widget code like this.

The problems are,

first: I can't update my selectedCity, it doesn't get an update. Also, the print function calls null, since my cityList data is like [new york, paris, london] etc...

second: flutter doesn't change focus from any TextField to DropdownButton fully. I mean, clicked TextField, then DropdownButton but focus reverts to that TextField after the button click. It is default action of Flutter?

```
  List<dynamic> _cityList;
  String _selectedCity;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton(
      value: _selectedCity,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 11,
        color: textColor,
      ),
      items: _cityList.map((city) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 4),
            child: Text(city),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (String value) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedCity = value;
          print(_selectedCity);
        });
      },
      isExpanded: true,
    );
  }
```

Edit: The solution of resetting FocusNode after selecting an item from DropdownMenuItem is adding this line inside of setstate like this:

this: `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());`

to here: `onChanged:(){setSate((){here}}`

Comment: You solution fixed something I have been searching for over the past 3 hours. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help you.  I have modified your code a little bit

```
 List<dynamic> _cityList;
 String _selectedCity;
```

It will show the Dropdown Button and when you click on it and select any value showing in the print

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              DropdownButton<String>(
                items: _cityList.map((dynamic value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: new Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedCity = value;
                    print(_selectedCity);
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!
The minor mistake is not adding the value parameter into my DropdownMenuItem. Others are same.

Comment: @mathronaut If above code helps you out, please accept the answer.

Comment: hai sunny @Sunny, i have dropdown, when i print value in onchanged function get null, what should i do?

Comment: @RohmatulLaily You need to check _cityList(Array List) Contains the data not the null value.

Answer (score 0):

for the focus problem you should use `focusNodes` one with the drop down list and another with the text field https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html.

Comment: Thank you for your effort, the solution is:


Adding this into DropdownMenuItem's setState:

FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());